# Use less/scss/sass with plugins that contain colors like morris charts

Tags: javascript, css, less

I got a website that needs to change colors by changing a single variable. That works fine except for the fact my website uses morris charts and datatables. Both of which have colors inside their JS files (which generate the elements).

So instead of changing one line of code, I have to change every place the color occurs in both JS files too.

Is there a way to tackle this?

Example part in my morris file:

```
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: ['iphone', 'ipad', 'itouch'],
    labels: ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod Touch'],
    pointSize: 3,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    pointStrokeColors:['#00bfc7', '#fdc006', '#9675ce'],
    behaveLikeLine: true,
    gridLineColor: '#e0e0e0',
    lineWidth: 1,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    lineColors: ['#00bfc7', '#fdc006', '#9675ce'],
    resize: true
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you compile SASS?
If you're using a task runner such as Gulp, you may use a plugin like [gulp-json-to-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-to-sass):

- Put all your variables in an external JSON file
- use the JSON file in SASS with Gulp and the provided plugin to compile SCSS into CSS
- import the same JSON file in your javascript code

When the setup is complete you will have all the variables defined in one place.